# How do I add a column based on a condition and assign values to it based on the syntax of values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column I wish to add called **"Survey Name"**. I am trying to use a conditional statement to add this column if it does not exist in the dataframe.

conditional column inserter code:

```
if "Survey Name" not in df2:
    df2.assign["Survey Name"]
```

Next. I wish to add the same value throughout the entire column. This value is based off of the syntax values of a column named **"Survey Sent Date"**

What I want it to do is to assign this value:
*"QxYY Our Voice - CBS"* where x is the quarter and YY is the year.
(E.g. if the date was "2022-03-23 08:00:00" then the value would be:
*"Q122 Our Voice - CBS"*

I already have something that can create syntax based on the **"Survey Sent Date"** I just need to assign its output as a value to the **"Survey Name"** column.

Quarter detection and syntax code:

```
"Q" + str(df2.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"].iloc[1].quarter) \
+ str(df2.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"].iloc[1].year)\ 
+ " Our Voice - CBS"
```

How would I use this Quarter detection and syntax code and attach it to the conditional column inserting code so that the output of the syntax code is assigned as a value in the newly inserted column?

The **"Survey Sent Date"** column is displayed like:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Survey Sent Date': ["2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00", \
                              "2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00"]})
    
df.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"], errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've converted your columns to datetime, you can do this quite easily using `dt` and `str` methods:

```
if "Survey Name" not in df:
    df["Survey Name"] = ("Q" 
                         + df['Survey Sent Date'].dt.quarter.astype(str) 
                         + df['Survey Sent Date'].dt.year.astype(str).str[2:] 
                         + " Our Voice - CBS")
```

Output:

```
       Survey Sent Date     Survey Name
0   2022-03-23 08:00:00     Q122 Our Voice - CBS
1   2022-03-23 08:00:00     Q122 Our Voice - CBS
2   2022-03-23 08:00:00     Q122 Our Voice - CBS
3   2022-03-23 08:00:00     Q122 Our Voice - CBS
4   2022-03-23 08:00:00     Q122 Our Voice - CBS
```

By the way, you can replace `df.loc[:, col]` with `df[col]`.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you, I suppose the last step was such a simple combination!

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply:

```
def my_logic(date):
    return "Q" + str(date.quarter) + str(date.year) + " Our Voice - CBS"

df = pd.DataFrame({'Survey Sent Date': ["2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00", \
                              "2022-03-23 08:00:00", "2022-03-23 08:00:00"]})

df.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "Survey Sent Date"], errors='coerce')

df["Survey Name"] = df["Survey Sent Date"].apply(my_logic)
```